# Parsing Successfully Until IndexError?

Tags: python

I have a script that's parsing for the first upper-case words in this file:

```
IMPORT fs

IF fs.exists("fs.pyra") THEN
    PRINT "fs.pyra Exists!" 
END
```

The script looks like this:

```
file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
file = file.read().split("\n")

while '' in file:
    findIt = file.index('')
    file.pop(findIt)

for line in file:
    func = ""
    index = 0
    while line[index] == " ":
        index = index + 1
    while not line[index] == " " or "=" and line[index].isupper():
        func = func + line[index]
        index = index + 1
    print func
```

All used modules are already imported.
I passed the file that's being parsed's path in the arguments, and I'm getting this output:

```
IMPORT
IF
PRINT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/source.py", line 20, in <module>
    while not line[index] == " " or "=" and line[index].isupper():
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Which means it's parsing successfully until the last argument in the list, and then it's not parsing it at all. How do I fix this?

Comment: `while not line[index] == " " or "="` isn't doing what you think it is - do you perhaps mean `in (' =')` instead?

Comment: `file.read().split("\n")`...? Why not `file.readlines()`?

Comment: @cricket_007 `file.readlines()` leaves the newline characters in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to increment the index on spaces - `line.strip()` will remove leading and trailing spaces.

You could `split()` the line on spaces to get words.

Then you can iterate over those strings and use `isupper()` to check whole words, rather than individual characters

---

Alternatively, run the whole file through a pattern matcher for `[A-Z]+`

---

Anyways, your error...

```
while not line[index] == " " or "="
```

The `or "="` is always True, so your index is going out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

If the file you're trying to process is compatible with Python's built in tokenizer, you can use that so it'll also handle stuff within quotes, then take the very first name token it finds in capitals from each line, eg:

```
import sys
from itertools import groupby
from tokenize import generate_tokens, NAME

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fin:
    # Tokenize and group by each line
    grouped = groupby(tokenize.generate_tokens(fin.readline), lambda L: L[4])
    # Go over the lines
    for k, g in grouped:
        try:
            # Get the first capitalised name
            print next(t[1] for t in g if t[0] == NAME and t[1].isupper())
        except StopIteration:
            # Couldn't find one - so no panic - move on
            pass
```

This gives you:

```
IMPORT
IF
PRINT
END
```